# Need help with chi-square test interpretation with adjusted residuals

Tags: categorical-data, chi-squared-test, spss, descriptive-statistics, residuals

I have conducted multiple **chi-square tests** to compare **3 customer segments** (1 cat variable, 3 groups) on different **categorical variables**. As the chi-square tests are not 2×2, I have asked **SPSS** to produce **adjusted residuals** to indicate which cells contribute the most to the large chi-square. The convention is that an adjusted residual **> or = to 2.0** indicates a significantly larger count for the cell; an adjusted residual **< or = to -2.0** indicates the opposite. **My question** is: when the overall test is significant, *can I still say something about the relationship between a segment and the percentages in those cells where the adjusted residuals are in between these values?* *Can I say things like "the segment is characterized by..." if for that specific category (level) there is no adjusted residual that is above or below that threshold?* In other words: *is there anything I can say about the relationship between a particular segment and those cells that do not have values above or below that threshold?*